# cURL - execute a command and save the Json result to file?

Tags: curl, cmd

I am trying to run this command on CMD and the command "appears" to run without errors but I am not sure if it is actually making the request. The results should be returned in a Json file.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v3" -H "x-api-key: <my_api_key>" \https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=X182XCD
```

[This](https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/mot-history-api) is the API documentation.

When I ran this code in CMD, I got this error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "\https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Removing the `\` from the `\https://` seems to solve it. But I'm not sure if this command is executing successfully. Or whether it is executing correctly and just needs the Json results to be saved. I just need the Json results to be saved to a file where I can then process them.

EDIT 1:
I ran the code as @gabriel-santos posted and this is what I got. No new file was created by the command in the root directory.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay solved it. Thanks to @GabrielSantos's answer, this is the working code:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v3" -H "x-api-key: <my_api_key>" https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests?registration=X182XCD -o myresponse.json
```

The `\` for the `registration` was stopping the paramater being accepted and the Json was staying blank.

If I remove `-o myresponse.json`, the result is printed on the CMD, which is also useful.

Lesson: If entire code going to be single CMD command, remove EVERY `\`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-o file` to store output to desired file. `\` will only sscape line break, so, if you are sending an one line command you don't need it, otherwise you should:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v3" \
-H "x-api-key: <my_api_key>" \
https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=X182XCD \
-o myresponse.json
```

Comment: Thank you. See edit :) New file was not created by the command when executed.

Comment: @KickAss forgot one "\". Copy and try again my code.